# why does my Pi clock survive a reboot without an RTC or internet?

Tags: ethernet, rtc

It seems time on my RPi 3B v1.2 survives a reboot without either an RTC or an internet connection. I was given the Pi used by someone else, but I'm pretty sure I don't see an RTC connected to it.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

It is configured as an AP and not connected to Ethernet.  I noticed that when I reboot, the time stays accurate.  For fun, I masked both `hostapd` and `systemd-timesyncd`, then rebooted a few times.  See below.  If anyone can suggest what's happening here that would be great.

```
               Local time: Tue 2021-06-08 13:04:38 ADT
           Universal time: Tue 2021-06-08 16:04:38 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: America/Halifax (ADT, -0300)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
root@alphaleonis:/home/simba# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:a8:12:a1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5  bytes 284 (284.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5  bytes 284 (284.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:fd:47:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@alphaleonis:/home/simba#
```

Then after a `shutdown -r now`, here's the same output.  Note the time change.

````
Password: 
root@alphaleonis:/home/simba# timedatectl status
               Local time: Tue 2021-06-08 13:06:38 ADT
           Universal time: Tue 2021-06-08 16:06:38 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: America/Halifax (ADT, -0300)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
root@alphaleonis:/home/simba# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:a8:12:a1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5  bytes 284 (284.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5  bytes 284 (284.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:fd:47:f4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

root@alphaleonis:/home/simba#```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV3em.jpg
````

Comment: I'm not sure why my image isn't showing up inline...sorry first noob post...  https://i.stack.imgur.com/rV3em.jpg

Comment: you have to put the ``` on a separate line otherwise the system thinks that all text is code

Comment: As long as the unit has remained powered on, that seems normal to me. Electricity still flows through the circuitry when you reboot.

Comment: The time is written to sd-card and restored on boot. Just test it: shut down the Pi and remove power for a few minutes. Then restore power and boot it and you will see the old time saved at shutdown. Time seems saved at regular intervals (about one per hour?) so that this even works if you don't shut down the system properly but instead just remove power.

Comment: I shutdown and left it for a few hours (still powered on though, so not quite like @Anonymous mentioned), and when I booted again the clock was set to the shut-off time.  Dug a bit deeper and found this in journal: ```Jun 08 15:18:27 alphaleonis systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.```

Comment: And that led to this, in man systemd-timesyncd: "systemd-timesyncd ... saves the local time to disk every time the clock has been synchronized and uses this to possibly advance the system realtime clock on subsequent reboots to ensure it (roughly) monotonically advances even if the system lacks a battery-buffered RTC chip."  So as long as it stays on and only reboots nightly, it will lose the time it takes to reboot, every 24hrs.  Hmmm.  Is there a way I can hook a shutdown and set a specific time?  Then I can cron my reboot relative to that time.

Comment: But, this suggests the time is written to SD card, as @Robert mentioned, ONLY "when the clock has been synchronized," which it never is if I don't have an RTC or network connection?  I.e., I can:
1. boot, and set the time manually
2. leave it running for a few hours, and the clock advances
3. reboot, and the clock will pick up where it left off (perhaps minus the reboot time, if timesyncd actually writes on shutdown rather than on sync?)

But if timesyncd only writes on sync, then when I reboot shouldn't it be back to epoch?

Comment: Hmmm...besides ```mufasa@alphaleonis:~ $ systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
* systemd-timesyncd.service
   Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is masked.)
   Active: inactive (dead)``` so there must be something else saving the time on shutdown?

Comment: DO NOT put detail in Comments! EDIT your question.

Comment: Thanks @Milliways.  Still learning.  I wasn't sure if editing the original question would notify commentors (assuming of course they had enabled notifications...)?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you actual Question is.

`fake-hwclock` (which runs by default on Raspberry Pi OS) saves the time on shutdown, and restores it on boot. It also saves time regularly (in case of crash or improper shutdown).

See `man fake-hwclock`

This is independent of any other clock programs, and works on a system with RTC (unless disabled - as suggested in some poor tutorials).

Under normal circumstances it will restore time to the time of last shutdown.

Comment: My question was how the time survives a reboot without an internet connection or an RTC.  If you meant to say "works on a system without RTC" (rather than 'with') then I think you've answered it!  Thank you.